# change values using excel VBA Do loop (change row values to column )

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Sheet]

Dears,
I am facing problem to write VBA code in loop for below shown image.

Please note that:

1. The Number of rows is dynamical
2. In one trip vehicle will more than one customer
3. Where the trip start until the trip end in row basis but i need to transfer to column basis (from trip start to Trip end)

Could please help to write VBA Code in loop or Array

Thank you,
Abdul Salam.

Comment: If the result is on the right side in the image posted, could you explain how you will make use of the result with empty rows. I would rather like the rows one below the other and maybe in another worksheet. Please do clarify.

Answer (score 0):

### Transpose Data

- Copy the code into a standard module, e.g. `Module1`.
- Carefully adjust the values in the constants section.
- You can use the same sheet, but edit the cells appropriately not to overwrite data.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub getHorizontal()

    ' Constants

    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "A1" ' The first cell including the headers.
    ' The following is a keyword that will trigger a new row in the result.
    Const srcTrigger As String = "Trip Start"
    ' Target
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const tgtFirst As String = "A1"
    ' The number of elements in 'tgtHeaders' will determine the number
    ' of columns in Source Range. If you have more columns, add more headers.
    Dim tgtHeaders As Variant
    tgtHeaders = Array("From", "To")
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    ' Declare Success Boolean ('Success').
    Dim Success As Boolean
    
    ' Define Source Data Range and Trigger Count.
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    ' Define Source First Cell Range ('cel').
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = ws.Range(srcFirst)
    ' Define Source Columns Count ('srcColumnsCount').
    Dim srcColumnsCount As Long
    srcColumnsCount = UBound(tgtHeaders) - LBound(tgtHeaders) + 1
    ' Define Find Range ('rng') i.e. the range from First Cell Range
    ' to the bottom cell of the last column.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Columns(cel.Column).Resize(ws.Rows.Count - cel.Row + 1, _
                                            srcColumnsCount) _
                                    .Offset(cel.Row - 1)
    Set ws = Nothing
    ' Define Source Last Non-Empty Cell Range ('cel').
    Set cel = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    ' Validate Source Last Non-Empty Cell Range.
    If cel Is Nothing Then
        GoTo ProcExit ' Find Range is empty (no headers).
    End If
    If cel.Row = rng.Row Then
        GoTo ProcExit ' Find Range consists of only the headers.
    End If
    ' Define Source Data Range ('rng').
    Set rng = rng.Resize(cel.Row - rng.Row).Offset(1)
    Set cel = Nothing
    ' Define Trigger Count ('srcTriggerCount').
    Dim srcTriggerCount As Long
    srcTriggerCount = Application.CountIf(rng.Columns(1), srcTrigger)
    ' Validate Trigger Count.
    If srcTriggerCount = 0 Then
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array.
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Source Array ('Source').
    ' Note: The validation of Source Last Non-Empty Cell Range is ensuring
    '       at least two rows in Source Range, so it is a one-liner.
    Dim Source As Variant
    Source = rng.Value
    Set rng = Nothing
    
    ' Write values from Source Array to Target Array.
    
    ' Define initial Target Array.
    Dim Target As Variant
    ReDim Target(1 To srcTriggerCount + 1, 1 To srcColumnsCount)
    'Write initial Headers.
    Dim ArrayOffset As Long
    Dim j As Long
    ArrayOffset = 1 - LBound(tgtHeaders)
    For j = 1 To srcColumnsCount
        Target(1, j) = tgtHeaders(j - ArrayOffset)
    Next j
    ' Define Target Current Number of Columns ('CurrNoC').
    Dim CurrNoC As Long
    CurrNoC = UBound(Target, 2)
    ' Declare additional variables for the upcoming For Next Loop.
    Dim CurrColumn As Long
    Dim CurrentFirst As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    k = 1
    ' Loop through rows of Source Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(Source)
        ' Write value in first column of current row
        ' to Current First ('CurrentFirst')
        CurrentFirst = Source(i, 1)
        ' Test if Current First is an error value.
        If IsError(CurrentFirst) Then
            ' Note: The possible error value will still be copied. This is just
            '       to avoid an error occurring when comparing Current First
            '       to Source Trigger in the next 'If' statement.
            CurrentFirst = Empty
        End If
        If CurrentFirst = srcTrigger Then
            k = k + 1
            CurrColumn = 0
        Else
            ' When last column of Target Array has been reached.
            If CurrColumn = CurrNoC Then
                ' Increase Current Number of Columns by Source Columns Count.
                CurrNoC = CurrNoC + srcColumnsCount
                ' Resize Target Array.
                ReDim Preserve Target(1 To UBound(Target), 1 To CurrNoC)
                ' Write Headers.
                For j = CurrNoC - srcColumnsCount + 1 To CurrNoC
                    Target(1, j) = Target(1, j - srcColumnsCount)
                Next j
            End If
        End If
        ' Write values from current row in Source Array to Target Array.
        For j = 1 To srcColumnsCount
            CurrColumn = CurrColumn + 1
            Target(k, CurrColumn) = Source(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    ' Write values from Target Array to Target Range.
    
    ' Define Target Worksheet ('ws').
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    ' Define Target First Cell Range ('cel').
    Set cel = ws.Range(tgtFirst)
    ' Clear contents from Target First Cell Range to the bottom-most cell
    ' of the last column in Target Range.
    cel.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - cel.Row + 1, CurrNoC).ClearContents
    ' Define Target Range ('rng').
    Set rng = cel.Resize(srcTriggerCount + 1, CurrNoC)
    ' Write values from Target Array to Target Range.
    rng.Value = Target
    
    ' Validate Success Boolean.
    
    Success = True

ProcExit:
    
    ' Inform user.
    
    If Success Then
        MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "Data not copied.", vbCritical, "Fail"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your valuable reply with amazing VBA code. after run this VBA code in same sheet (last column of the sheet1) its sorting its self (its eliminate the empty rows in between trip starts) could please help?